# First time with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Regarding [Getting Started with Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/05/getting-started-with-twilio-video.html)

both me and the other side will require token form the server, right ?! , will this cost money or the calling video after start (in pricing they Room Participant  Programmable Video's Rooms connect your users in a multi-party voice or video session cost $0.01 per hour for one participant ) ,

am not sure about other-name in invitation method  meaning the other side token you mean ?! or what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really the place to talk about pricing, but I'll go ahead and answer it anyway:

The token from the server does not cost anything (you generate that on your own backend for the users to connect). Once you get the access token, you would then connect to the room. Each user that connects to the room will be charged the initial $0.01 charge (the per hour charge).

Example:
Two users talk in a room for 20 seconds: Cost is $0.02.
Two users talk in a room for 59 minutes: Cost is $0.02.
Two users talk in a room for 1.5 hours: Cost is $0.04.

Twilio also has TURN (you can disable this), which would kick-in if the WebRTC peer to peer is not functioning. If you choose to use it, it is charged per GB regionally. Current pricing details for TURN are [here](https://www.twilio.com/stun-turn/pricing).